# How to upload csv files through Rest APIs using Jersey (Java)?

Tags: java, rest, csv, jersey

I have a requirement to upload csv file through upload API but having difficulty to add thta support in framework.
I am using jersey as tool and using below maven dependency for multipart support.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help with some sample code to help me implement file upload (csv, xlsx etc.) via Rest API.

Answer (score 3):

To upload a file to the server, you can send the file content in the request payload using, for example, [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3). The [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) of the request should be `multipart/form-data` and your resource method must be annotated with `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`.

In Jersey you could use the [`@FormDataParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html) annotation to bind the named body part(s) of a `multipart/form-data` request entity body to a resource method parameter, as following:

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
                       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) {
    ...
}
```

To use multipart features you need to add the [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.25.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all needed dependencies (see [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.25.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html)) on the classpath.

You also need to register the [`MultiPartFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) in your [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) / [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

For more details, check the [Jersey documentation about multipart requests](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart).

If you need to manipulate XLS/XLSX files, you can consider the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) project.